# How do I avoid bracketed [...] of help message when nargs='+'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I am trying to write a command-line interface using the `argparse` module in Python, but I'm running into trouble with the help message for one of my arguments. The argument should take either 1 argument (filename) or 3 arguments (filename, column, column), so this is how I approached it:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--score', nargs ='+', help='score file, default X Y = 2 4',
     metavar='FILENAME X Y')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

and then an if-else:

```
if len(args.score) == 1:
     data = open(args.score[0])
     S1 = 1
     S2 = 3
elif len(args.score) == 3:
     data = open(args.score[0])
     S1 = int(args.score[1]) - 1
     S2 = int(args.score[2]) - 1
else:
     print('Error: --score incorrect number of arguments called')
```

But my help message looks like this:

```
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --score FILENAME X Y [FILENAME X Y ...]
                        score file, default X Y = 2 4
```

and I want the bracketed portion to go away:

```
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --score FILENAME X Y  score file, default X Y = 2 4
```

---

**EDIT**
Here's how I chose to implement the fix, albeit as a hacky workaround, using ANSI escape codes:

```
parser.add_argument('--score', nargs ='+', help='\x1b[A\b\b\b\b\b\b X Y \x1b[1C\b score file, default X Y = 2 4',
    metavar=('FILENAME', ''))
```

gives the output

```
usage: test.py [-h] [--score FILENAME [...]]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --score FILENAME X Y  score file, default X Y = 2 4
```

Thanks to @hpaulj for the metavar tuple idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the `metavar` the help is:

```
usage: ipython3 [-h] [--score SCORE [SCORE ...]]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --score SCORE [SCORE ...]
                        score file, default X Y = 2 4
```

`SCORE` is derived from the longname, and `'%s [%s ...]' % get_metavar(2)` formatting.

If I change the metavar to a tuple of 2 items, they replace those two instances of `SCORE`

```
usage: ipython3 [-h] [--score NAME [XY ...]]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --score NAME [XY ...]
                        score file, default X Y = 2 4
```

With nargs=3, I could give these words in the metavar and get:

```
usage: ipython3 [-h] [--score NAME X Y]
....
```

Splitting that input into 2 arguments gives

```
In [774]: parser.add_argument('--FILENAME', help='score file', metavar='NAME');
In [775]: parser.add_argument('--XY', nargs=2, help='x,y');  # type=int
In [776]: parser.print_help()

usage: ipython3 [-h] [--FILENAME NAME] [--XY XY XY]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help       show this help message and exit
  --FILENAME NAME  score file
  --XY XY XY       x,y
```

=================

The actual format is produced by the `HelpFormatter._format_args` method:

```
def _format_args(self, action, default_metavar):
    get_metavar = self._metavar_formatter(action, default_metavar)
    ....
    elif action.nargs == ONE_OR_MORE:
        result = '%s [%s ...]' % get_metavar(2)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is very nonstandard in the world of command line interfaces.  You should redesign your argument syntax.  Instead of supporting these two:

```
--score FILENAME
--score FILENAME X Y
```

You should consider one of these alternatives:

```
--score FILENAME [-x X] [-y Y]
--score FILENAME[=X,Y]
```

Both of which will be easy to support using standard command line argument parsing libraries.